# Jquery click event not binding on <a> tag when JavaScript put it in separate file

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a piece of code that is working fine when i put it on page and it is not working when i put the script in a separate file.

## SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id*=SearchLocator]').on("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $('#SearchStoreLocator').trigger("click");
        }
    });

    $('#SearchStoreLocator').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchLocator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="PostCodeSearchValidation"
ToolTip="Enter an address" MaxLength="200" CssClass="AddressSearch" />
<a id="SearchStoreLocator">Find</a>.
```

## Rendered HTML

```
<input name="ctl00$PageContent$Survey$ctl06$SearchLocator" type="text" maxlength="200" id="ctl00_PageContent_Survey_ctl06_SearchLocator" title="Enter an address" class="AddressSearch" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="off">
<a id="SearchStoreLocator">Find</a>
```

I dont know whats going on here... just a `hello alert` is not displayed when i click on the link (when i put the script in a separate file)

## Jquery version

```
jquery-1.8.3.min.js
jquery-1.9.1.min.js

both are loaded on the page, BUT other things are working fine except only this <a> tag. 

NOTE: i am loading jquery twice as there are some things that are not supported by jquery-1.8.3
```

## EDIT

```
after removing jquery-1.8.3.min.js still not working...
```

Comment: I think you are missing DOM ready wrapper. Include your script in DOM ready.

Comment: Why are you loading jquery twice?

Comment: why are you using two version's of jQuery and DOM ready missing ?

Comment: DOM ready is there but i did not include it in here ....

Comment: there are things on the page that are not supported by jquery-1.8.3

Comment: So don't use 1.8.3, only use 1.9.1

Comment: Can we see where/how you're including the external JS file?

Comment: same code i puting in JS file and referencing it into the page... other things works fine when i do that except this <a> tag

Comment: If you are adding jquery twice you are overwriting $, it the same as only adding the last

Comment: OK .. let me remove it...

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- ASP.Net doesn´t use the exact ID in the client side (rendered) [ClientID MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx), to do it so use the property ClientID, I think you can edit in the web.config
- Only use one jQuery, I recommend the jquery-1.9.1.min.js
- Are you adding your script file where the script is located after jquery

Comment: well, as you can see the ID isnt changed in rendered HTML... after referencing external JS, everything works except this <a> tag

Comment: Have you try debugging the script the chrome developer tools or firebug to see is the script is executing or if the event is attached

Comment: no error in console. i dont know how to check if the event is attached... can you please send me some example.

Comment: The NO error indicates everything loaded correctly for see if events are atached event use [Chrome Events](http://infoheap.com/use-chrome-developer-tools-to-view-event-handlers/) or look up in google for setting breakpoints in JS to see if the script is executing

Answer (score 1):

I think you can select them with this : I mean the End of Id should be equal with 'SearchLocator'

```
  **$('a [id$=SearchLocator]')**
```

or

```
  **$('[id$=SearchLocator]')**
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  using [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

```
   if (event.which== 13) {
       $('#SearchStoreLocator').trigger("click");
   }
```